# Fazer $_SESSION funcionar como session_register

Tags: php, session

Alterei meus `session_register` para `$_SESSION`, entretanto `$_SESSION` não me permite usar a variável da mesma maneira que `session_register`.

Por estar *deprecated* pensei que correspondiam a mesma coisa. No entanto o uso após a declaração é bem diferente, as variáveis de sessão geradas pelo session_register podem ser usadas normalmente, as deplacaras pelo $_SESSION não.

```
$nome = "Haxz";
session_register("nome");
```

Após a declaração, simplesmente usando `$nome` ele já me devolve o valor. Como uma variável comum.

```
$_SESSION["nome"] = "Haxz";
```

Não me permite usar a variável como `$nome`, apenas como `$_SESSION["nome"]`.

O que me intriga é que ambas podem ser testadas da mesma forma `isset($_SESSION["nome"])` e no `print_r($_SESSION)`, são mostradas igual.

Não quero alterar todo o meu projeto (ele é bem grande) 
Como fazer a `$_SESSION["nome"]` responder igual a `session_register("nome")` ?
(responder no sentido de poder trabalhar com ela só com uma variável `$nome` correspondente.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não faça isso.

Simplesmente faça assim ao final do código:

```
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
```

E no começo recupere com

```
    $nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
```

...Mas se realmente quiser fazer, uma solução seria essa:

```
function meu_session_register($nome){
    global $$nome;
    $_SESSION[$nome] = $$nome;
    $$nome = &$_SESSION[$nome]; 
}
```

Explicação:

- primeiro, declaramos uma variável global com o mesmo `$nome` da variável;
- em seguida, guardamos na sessão o valor
- depois, re-atribuimos o valor à variável passando por referência (`&`), para que alterações subsequentes alterem o valor da sessão.

Comment: Então, de fato o $_SESSION não é uma versão mais recente do session_register... Achei que houvesse alguma coisa até mesmo com o php.ini que estivesse errada. Obrigado.

Comment: @Haxz o session_register já trabalha com $_SESSION, são interfaces pra mesma estrutura. o $_SESSION ja existe faz tempo tb. Pelo $_SESSION vc ja acessava os dados de um session_register das suas aplicações.

Comment: compreendo. Fiquei preocupado com a _Notice_ e acabei confundindo a estrutura... Obrigado mesmo, vou usar MUITO essa função.

Comment: @Haxz eu gostaria que você com o tempo nao precisasse mais da função. É sério, se vc acostumar a pegar as variaveis da sessão no começo, e guardar depois de usar, vai inclusive ter uma visão melhor do seu código. Enquanto isso, prefixe todas com "$session_", pra vc ao menos separar o que é de sessão e o que não.

Comment: O problema não é esse, o projeto já está no meio do caminho (estou atualizando na verdade) e não vai ter como alterar tudo pra `$_SESSION`.